# Selecting rows if at least values in one column satisfy a condition using Pandas any

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'gene':["foo","bar","qux","woz"], 'cell1':[5,0,1,0], 'cell2':[12,90,13,0]})
df = df[["gene","cell1","cell2"]]
```

Which looks like this:

```
  gene  cell1  cell2
0  foo      5     12
1  bar      0     90
2  qux      1     13
3  woz      0      0
```

What I want to do is to select the rows based on if the at least one value from 2nd column onwards is greater than 2. Yielding this:

```
  gene  cell1  cell2
0  foo      5     12
1  bar      0     90
2  qux      1     13
```

I tried this but it doesn't give me what I want:

```
df[(df.values > 2).any(axis=1)]
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should select `cell1` and `cell2` and then check them against `2`. Example -

```
In [4]: df[(df[['cell1','cell2']] > 2).any(axis=1)]
Out[4]:
   cell1  cell2 gene
0      5     12  foo
1      0     90  bar
2      1     13  qux
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
df[(df.cell1 > 2).any(axis=1)]
```

By second column, I wasn't sure if you were talking about cell1 or cell2...